# using paste() to construct windows path in R

Tags: windows, r

I am trying to take two character vectors:

```
directory <- "specdata"
id <- 1
```

and read the data in from the file that they would "point" to: ie:

```
data <- read.table(paste(directory,"\\",id,".csv", sep="")
```

The problem is in the result of paste and the "\". I am trying to get it to return `"specdata\1.csv"` however it returns `"specdata\\1.csv"` which is not the same.

To no avail, I have also tried:

- using a single-slash `"\"`
- using single quotes like `'\\'`
- using single quotes like `'\'`
- changing sep = `'\'`
- changing sep = `'\\'`
- changing sep = `"\"`
- changing sep = `"\\"`
- using the c() function first like

code:

```
fileNameAndPath <- c(directory,"\",id,".csv")
data <- read.table(fileNameAndPath)
```

Comment: You missed the obvious `/` which R allows, and you want to understand about escaping slashed -- so `\\` really needs `\\\\`.  That said, `file.path()` is *the* way to go as @sgibb showed you.

Comment: This is a very old question (almost a decade) but I think that `specdata\\1.csv` should work as well.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use `file.path` instead (it is independent of your platform):

```
file.path(directory, paste(id, ".csv", sep=""))
```

Comment: file.path is what I was looking for, but now more generally, how would one other concatenate the three strings "hi" "\" and "mom" ? Is file.path the only way to put a slash between strings?

Comment: Note that `nchar("\\")` is still 1, so although it looks different it is still actually a single slash.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question to put the \ examples in code divs to demonstrate that I understand that... still yet the question exists why paste doesn't work as I expect it to

Comment: It's not clear what you're still not understanding and/or what's not working.  For understanding what @James is saying, notice that after storing `f <- paste(directory,"\\",id,".csv", sep="")`, `print(f)` and `cat(f)` are different.  `cat` prints the actual values, while `print` uses the `\\` as `\` is a special character.