# Two PASTE functions in a character vector

Tags: r

```
attach.files = c(paste("/users/joesmith/nosection_", currentDate,".csv",sep=""), 
                       paste("/users/joesmith/withsection_", currentDate,".csv",sep=""))
```

Basically, if I did it like

```
c("nosection_051418.csv", "withsection_051418.csv")
```

And I did that manually it would work fine but since I'm automating this to run every day I can't do that.

I'm trying to attach files in an automated email but when I structure it like this, it doesn't work. How can I recreate this so that the character vector accepts it?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? What you have should generate an appropriate string . . . Are you sure the paths are in the correct format?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650260/using-paste-to-construct-windows-path-in-r?rq=1

Comment: It won't make the result any different, but you might prefer `sprintf` for "fill-in-the-blank" style pasting, it's a little more readable: `c(sprintf("/users/joesmith/nosection_%s.csv", currentDate), ...)`

Answer (score 0):

I thought your example implied the need for "parallel" inputs to the path stem, the first portion of the file name, and the date portions of those full paths. Consider this illustration of using a 2 item vector and a one item vector (produced by Sys.Date, replacing your "currentdate") to populate the `%s` positions in that `sprintf` string (suggested by @Gregor):

```
 sprintf("/users/joesmith/%s_%s.csv", c("nosection", "withsection"), Sys.Date() )
[1] "/users/joesmith/nosection_2018-05-14.csv"   "/users/joesmith/withsection_2018-05-14.csv"
```