# how to reclassify a batch of rasters in R

Tags: r, lapply, spatial, raster, tiff

I am trying to run the same reclassify on a bunch of raster (.tif) files in R. I followed the example from the following code:

```
wfrastlist <- list.files(path = 
                           "/path/to/directory", pattern='*.TIF$', all.files=TRUE, full.names=FALSE)

#generate a reclassification matrix 
#in this example, values less than 353.2 are assigned a new value of 'NA'
m <- c(-Inf, 353.2, NA)
rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

#function to reclassify rasters and write a new reclassified tif file for each
batch_reclass <- function(wfrastlist){
  for (i in 1:length(wfrastlist)) {
    #read in raster
    r <- raster(paste0("/path/to/directory", wfrastlist[i]))

    #perform the reclassifcation
    rc <- reclassify(r, rclmat)

    #write each reclass to a new file 
    writeRaster(rc, filename = paste0("/path/to/newdirectory", "rc_", 
                                      wfrastlist[i]), format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
  }
}
#run the function
batch_reclass(wfrastlist)
```

But I get the following error msg:

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 

Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist) 
6. stop("Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not 
exist)") 
5..rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer", 
...) 
4..local(x, ...) 
3. raster(paste0("/Users/rachelfield/Documents/UBC/MyNetworks/ES_maps/data/wf_rasters _by_basin", 
wfrastlist[i])) 
2. raster(paste0("/Users/rachelfield/Documents/UBC/MyNetworks/ES_maps/data/wf_rasters_by_basin", 
wfrastlist[i])) 
1. batch_reclass(wfrastlist)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Code example obtained from here:
https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/250928_2ab49213bf0047cc9cd02e1745858dd3.html

Comment: maybe a missing `/`? - `raster(paste0("/path/to/directory", wfrastlist[i]))` should be `raster(paste0("/path/to/directory/", wfrastlist[i]))`

Comment: To add to @dww's comment, it's safer to use `file.path()` to construct paths in R https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650260/using-paste-to-construct-windows-path-in-r

Comment: yes, adding the missing / worked! Thanks so much, dww

Comment: @Dorothy i am trying to use the same workflow for a similar problem. what does `-inf` in your case or `-999` represent as 3rd argument in defining reclassification matrix

Comment: the '-Inf' represents the low extent of values being negative infinity. So the reclassification range includes all negative numbers and positive numbers less than 353.2 (the second argument value)